File *.trc is not a recognizable trace file
I am getting the following alert only for one trace file:
File 'xxx.trc' is not a recognizable trace file.
I can select from all other trace files using fn_trace_gettable.
Is it safe to delete this 0 bytes file to stop the alert?
thank you

This trace file is either empty or corrupted, but the fact it has 0 bytes, is likely, that it doesn’t contain any valuable data. Deleting this trace file shouldn’t affect your system. I recommend checking whether the file is in use by any process and whether any relevant data is missing despite the file being 0 bytes it is better to double-check before deletion.

oh...thank you so much for your time @severalnines My sincere apologies for not coming back to update, I've only just seen your response now. The file had rolled over and been automatically removed on server reboots. Thanks again for your time and your helpful response.
